# Repo in CYGWIN got error like "Python can not open file 'user/bin/repo'"

Tags: android, cygwin, repository

I have Windows 7 on my pc and I just wanna check out the Android source by following the steps here:http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

I tried CYGWIN and followed exactly what the tutorial told.
But got no luck here:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1
```

CYGWIN bash told me this:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '/home/qhuang/bin/repo': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Actually this file exists and it may need a prefix:

```
C:\cygwin\
```

in windows.

Big thanks to anyone helps!

Answer (score 3):

To help out anyone who (like me) hits this question later on. This was solved for me after installing python within Cygwin (I had python installed in Windows, but not Cygwin). You can check if it is installed with 'which python' if it comes back as C:/blah/python then you don't have it installed in Cygwin; you want /usr/bin/python to come back letting you know it is the internal Cygwin one.

Comment: It's been years but I do think this is the solution.

Answer (score -2):

Try `cd C:\cygwin\` , maybe that helps

Comment: No luck:    $ cd c:\cygwin\
    > repo
    -bash: cd: c:cygwinrepo: No such file or directory

Comment: No it should be like  cd c:\cygwin\ and then $ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format it but it just says No such file or directory. And If I use 'cd ..' to get to the top directory and type 'repo' it says "can't open file" again, same as I type it in the "~" directory.

Comment: Did what you suggest but still the same "No such file or directory"